# How to hide secondary sub menu item when click on menu button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok I am trying to create an accordance style menu with sub-menu in it but when I click the hamburger button, my secondary sub-menu also shows up by default. How to hide "list 2" when first click on the hamburger? I mean when click on hamburger only show "list 1" without showing "list 2" until you click on "list 1".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $(".primary-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".primary-list").click(function() {
        $(".standard-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>&#9776;</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>

      <ul>
        <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you not trying to reinvent a `tree`-style navigation element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `$(".standard-list").slideToggle("fast");` at first in the document.ready() function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".standard-list").slideToggle("fast");
      $("button").click(function() {
        
        $(".primary-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".primary-list").click(function() {
        $(".standard-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>&#9776;</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>

      <ul>
        <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary-list"><a href="#">list 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first - use just one $(document).ready();
second - use $(this)
3rd - its better to use .on(); its avoid any errors you will may facing 
4th - you can use display: none; for your sub-menu css  or add $(".standard-list").hide(); to hide your sub-menu on load

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").on('click',function() {
        $(".primary-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
      $(".primary-list").on('click',function() {

        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
  </script>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wuwkqrb2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that standard-list is inside of primary-list, so when you click on standard, you also click on primary. You need the class on something that is not wrapped around the standard list.

```
<li class="primary-list"><a class="toggle-standard" href="#">list 1</a>

  <ul>
    <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="standard-list"><a href="#">list 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>


$(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $(".primary-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".toggle-standard").click(function() {
        $(".standard-list").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Forklift/7w73otch/